# Cake php default pagination to get first and last page pagination links

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to get Cake php default pagination to get first and last page pagination link

```
<p>
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
        'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true)
    ));
    ?>    </p>

<div class="paging">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
    |     <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>
    |
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
</div>
```

This will output

```
Page 1 of 89, showing 15 records out of 1326 total, starting on record 1, ending on 15

<< previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | next >>
```

How would I get first and last page links also with default pagination

```
first | << previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | next >> | last
```

Comment: for first and last there will be link or not,, or you just want to show text ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried this code and it is working in cakephp 1.3 for me:--

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('<< First', true), array('class' => 'number-first'));?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers', 'first' => false, 'last' => false));?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('>> Last', true), array('class' => 'number-end'));?>
```

try to implement this...

this is what you are looking for:--

```
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('First', true), array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
|     <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('Previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
|     <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers', 'first' => false, 'last' => false));?>
|     <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
|     <?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Last', true), array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but simply open the help page:

[PaginatorHelper::first()](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperfirst)

[PaginatorHelper::last()](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperlast)

Comment: is this method is also for cakephp 1.3 ... i serched in google or book.cakephp but it doesn't seems to work..

Comment: @Learner: Actually, I just double-checked it in the API, I've updated the links

Answer (score 0):

For cakephp-3.x

You always wanted First page link will be displayed, when you reach to page 5 or higher, you can use:

```
<?php if ($this->Paginator->counter('{{page}}') >= 5): ?>
    <li class="">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->first('First'); ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Similarly for the last, there is no need of the last page link if you have only 5 or pages or less. In that case you can use:

```
<?php if ($this->Paginator->counter('{{pages}}') > 5): ?>
    <li class="paginate_button last">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->last('Last') ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```